Failed to connect to LDAP server.: javax.naming.AuthenticationException
I have configured ldap in Jboss instance, however it's not being connected to ldap server and throws below error.
02:50:08,512 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1) Obtaining lock for identity [user1]...
02:50:08,513 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1) Obtained lock for identity [user1].
02:50:08,517 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1) Creating [class javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext] with environment:
02:50:08,517 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1)     Property [java.naming.security.credentials] with value [******]
02:50:08,517 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1)     Property [java.naming.security.authentication] with value [simple]
02:50:08,518 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1)     Property [java.naming.provider.url] with value [ldap://ldap_server:3268]
02:50:08,518 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1)     Property [com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout] with value [60000]
02:50:08,518 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1)     Property [com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool] with value [false]
02:50:08,518 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1)     Property [com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout] with value [5000]
02:50:08,518 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1)     Property [java.naming.security.principal] with value [CN=svc_account,OU=IT,DC=local,DC=xxx,DC=xxx]
02:50:08,518 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1)     Property [java.naming.referral] with value [ignore]
02:50:08,519 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1)     Property [java.naming.factory.initial] with value [com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory]
02:50:08,536 DEBUG [org.wildfly.security] (management task-1) Could not create [class javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext]. Failed to connect to LDAP server.: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090449, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839]


What's your question? How did you test the connection? Please read the formatting help.

error 52e means invalid credentials, ensure that the login/password provided is correct..

I was using an incorrect OU for the principal, modifying the details to correct values which resolved this error.

Active Directory no longer allows by default unsecure binds that send credentials unencrypted in plain text.
You should update the code to establish a secure (TLS) connection. Then connect to the secure port (636/3269).
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/2020-2023-and-2024-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-for-windows-kb4520412-ef185fb8-00f7-167d-744c-f299a66fc00a
